# PHP MySQL Convert Timestamp to 'ago' format

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp, time-format

I want to make a time ago format from my `timestamp` value but it shows wrong value. I have read a lot of topics about the timestamp to time ago format but I haven't found the answer. Maybe you can help me.

I have a page that displays all the users with their infos.
Here's the code:

Some basic info: All the timestamp values are the same in my database (2021-03-25 20:46:48) but the output is: `0 days 6 hours`

```
<?php
include "dbConn.php"; // Using database connection file here
$records = mysqli_query($db,"select * from accounts"); // fetch data from database
while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) {}

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "phplogin");
if ($conn-> connect_error) {
die("Connection failed:". $conn-> connect_error);
}
$ssql = "SELECT * FROM accounts";
$result =  $conn-> query($ssql);
if ($result-> num_rows > 0) {
while ($roww = $result-> fetch_assoc()) {
$id = $roww['id'];
echo "
<td>Joined:</td>
<td>";
$time = strtotime($roww['timestamp']);
$dbDate = new DateTime($time);
$currDate = new DateTime();
$interval = $currDate->diff($dbDate);
echo $interval->d." days ".$interval->h." hours";
echo "</td>
```

Comment: Heard about or used a library called Carbon? I'd suggest using that, instead of building your own logic for ago. Since that library will already cover the ago, according to how much difference is in of the timestamp from db and current time.


You can certainly build your own ago format logic. But sometimes it's good to not re-invent the wheel!

[Check the Carbon Library](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

Comment: Whats the "raw" Output of your $interval? (dump)